# Binary Smoothing Fingerprint Image Filter in C# Using SourceAFIS Library Not Works

Tags: c#, image-processing, filter, fingerprint

I am working on fingerprint analysis software ,and i  want to do the BinarySmoothing Filter of [SourceAFIS](https://sourceafis.angeloflogic.com/) library ,

**Original Image**

[image: OriginalImage]

**Result Needed**

[image: Result Needed]

But I am not getting the same result from below code

```
    DpiAdjuster.Adjust(this, 500, delegate()
                            {
    
                                byte[,] image = ImageInverter.GetInverted(fp1.Image);
    
                                BlockMap blocks = new BlockMap(new SourceAFIS.General.Size(image.GetLength(1), image.GetLength(0)), BlockSize);
                               
                                short[, ,] histogram = Histogram.Analyze(blocks, image);
                                short[, ,] smoothHistogram = Histogram.SmoothAroundCorners(blocks, histogram);
                                BinaryMap mask = Mask.ComputeMask(blocks, histogram);
                                float[,] equalized = Equalizer.Equalize(blocks, image, smoothHistogram, mask);
    
                                byte[,] orientation = Orientation.Detect(equalized, mask, blocks);
                                float[,] smoothed = RidgeSmoother.Smooth(equalized, orientation, mask, blocks);
                                float[,] orthogonal = OrthogonalSmoother.Smooth(smoothed, orientation, mask, blocks);
    
                                BinaryMap binary = Binarizer.Binarize(smoothed, orthogonal, mask, blocks);
                                binary=BinarySmoother.Filter(binary);
}
```

But  i am getting this Output

**Outupt Getting**

[image: Output]

Please Help

Comment: have you got the solution?